# Is it possible in Geomagic Studio to compute volume via Python macro?

Tags: python, macros, volume

I'm using Python scripts to realize macros in Geomagic Studio 2012.
I need to calculate, on a set of scanned objects, the volume of several of them respect to the total.

Currently, I:

- write down the volume calculated via Geomagic menu with "compute volume";
- split the original model obtaining as many models as the island of polygons are;
- for some models, still via menu, compute and write down their volumes;
- find my desired percentage of volume of interesting models divided by the total volume of the set.

Is it possible to automate the reading/writing of the volume of each model, and calculate the final percentage?

(The only reference on "compute volume" function in Geomagic Support Center is here, but it's not well written: http://support1.geomagic.com/link/portal/5605/5668/Article/870/What-are-some-known-parameters-of-existing-macros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giovanni,

There is a KB Article on the **query macro**.  It allows programmatic access to the volume (for a closed manifold polymesh), surface area, and center of gravity...and others.  Here's the link:

http://support1.geomagic.com/ics/support/KBAnswer.asp?questionID=2236&hitOffset=190+99+90+83

It uses the geo. macro module so it is compatible with 2012 and can be mixed with the v1 Python API.  The API help docs are installed with 2012 and should have examples for getting the list of models and iterating over them. The docs are located in the install folder, by default (for Studio):

C:\Program Files\Geomagic\Geomagic Studio 2012\help\platform\index.html

-Richard

Comment: Hello Richard,
thanks a lot for having created the related topic on KB, I really needed it!
I'd like to take this opportunity to thank you also for all the precious information i found on your "Flying Circus" blog, I feel honored I've talked with you.